# Jenkins(not local) is not able to find input sheet(.xlsx)

Tags: jenkins

My jar file is working fine when I m executing it with the help of .bat file on local Jenkins.

But Whn I am executing the same code/jar in Organization's Jenkins,its unable to find the Input file.It is giving me below errors

```
 INFO [main] (Base.java:18) - Firefox Launching....
Browser Launched for Test Case : Admin_GetNextLead
**java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ayan_Haldar\workspace2\test\Test\test\TestData.xlsx (The system cannot find the path specified)**
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at subscripts.XcelReader.ExcelFile(XcelReader.java:29)
    at test.Admin_GetNextLead.test(Admin_GetNextLead.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at test.RunTest.main(RunTest.java:132)
Browser Closed for Test Case : Admin_GetNextLead
result:false
```

Can you help me out??

Comment: C:\Users\Ayan_Haldar\workspace2\test\Test\test\TestData.xlsx - does this file exist on the organizations CI server?! Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your organization's jenkins machine has a path `C:\Users\Ayan_Haldar\workspace2\test\Test\test\TestData.xlsx`. This path exists in your local jenkins machine but not exists in your organization's jenkins machine.

Comment: can you pls elaborate??